# Clicking on x -y co ordinates of the browser using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on UI similar to the shapes in MS Paint, MS Words.
The shape is made using x-y co ordinates of the browser as no element is associated with it.

Following is the code, which I am using to draw rectangle, I am unable to draw it :

```
pyautogui.click(x=800,y=500,)
pyautogui.dragTo(x=1000,y=800,button='left')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.doubleClick(x=400,y=400)
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: My ui consits of arcgis map and i want to make a rectangle on it so there are no elements associated with it so i chose to click the browser using x y cordinates of the browser.
The rectangle is made with same steps as we use to draw it on software like paint and word etc. u click on certain point hold and drag it to certain length and double click the mouse to end it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Actions class which having functionality of drag and drop

Example code :-

```
    source1 = driver.find_element_by_id('draggable')
    action = ActionChains(driver)

    #move element by x,y coordinates on the screen
    action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(source1, 100, 100)
```

Below are some reference:-

https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/intermediate-topics/drag-and-drop-scenarios/

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/10/selenium-webdriver-drag-and-drop.html

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: hey shubham,
 source1 = driver.find_element_by_id('draggable').
There is no id associated with...its like map on which i want to make a rectangle.
So more like clicking on certain co ordinates of the browser(screen) then making a rectangle

Comment: Thats the example code .. replace it with your rectangular locator

Comment: you have to find it using any locator example xpath

Comment: No sorry shubham but your understanding is wrong rectangle is not an element it is made...like we make a rectangle in paint or word.This rectangle is made on map which is my UI

Comment: can you find any element on your paint sheet section. so we can instruct selenium to start dragging from that location. Can you place more detail in question like image, HTML code so we can have a look better of your situation